# Pyinstaller y código fuente de la aplicación generada

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Tengo una duda, a lo largo que llevo usando **Pyinstaller** he notado que en los archivos generados se conserva el código fuente de la aplicación, sin embargo hoy simplemente de curioso eliminé los archivos del código fuente, (aquellos .py) y noté que la aplicación seguía funcionando en su totalidad, ¿Esto puede ser una buena practica para proteger el código fuente o es sencillamente suerte y depende de cada aplicación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Python` tiene un sistema de cache que puede a veces causarte una mala jugada. Te invito a que elimines los archivos terminados `.pyc` que suelen estar en una carpeta llamada `__pycache__`. Una vez lo hallas eliminado genera nuevamente el instalador. Si aun asi tienes este inconveniente te recomiendo hasta reiniciar tu equipo. Si al final sigue pasando seguramente  hay algo en tu código que no esta bien.

Si solucione tu duda cuéntame, feliz día!